# Python program executable for windows

Tags: python, linux, windows, py2exe, python-3.5

I have Linux installed and Python 3.5. The program itself is made in Linux but i need to make it executable in windows. I cant see any program that can do this for python 3.5. Please give me some working option. pyinstaller, cx_freeze and py2exe dont work with 3.5 [image]

After fighting with depends for some time i got it here:
[image]
Needles to say its not starting the exe...

Comment: PyInstaller .... supports..... 3.5..... `Multiversion: supports Python 2.7 and Python 3.3, 3.4 and 3.5.` from their site http://www.pyinstaller.org/

Comment: Edited my post with one of many errors. I would not be here if it works........

Comment: so @MooingRawr ....its....not....working with 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So problem solved. 
For Python 3.5 after you install `pyinstaller` via `pip` you need also to install `Microsoft visual C++ Redistributable package x86` 2010 and 2015 to cover missing `dll`-s you need. After that, when `.exe` is made you need to point the `PyQt5` `bin` folder. So finally my command is this:

```
C:\Project> "C:\Python35-32\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe" --paths C:\Python32-35\Lib\site-packages\Pyqt5\Qt\bin --onefile --noconsole main.pyw
```

This wont work without VC_Redistributable packages or even if it does it wont start afterwards, showing errors for missing `dll` files.
This will feed the `.exe` only the libraries so other files (`png,txt`) will still have to be in the root folder of the executable.

Answer (score 0):

No worries ;)

cx_freeze is currently coming out as version 5.0 for Python 3.5. There is an unstable version of cx_freeze which utilizes a quite hard way to do but here is a GitHub guide to follow > http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net

As for pyinstaller you can watch this video which should help you > https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=11Q2QADsAEE

I hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: i cannot understand the guide to 5.0 :) 
pyinstaller video doesnt work for 3.5. After a lot of tweaking i can make an exe that is not starting. I am in panic. Nothing is working

Comment: i will be very greatfull for some help. I got like 6 python files in a project with 1 main class. I need to include PyQt5 and xlsxwriter, requests, and several more libs.

Comment: I am looking into it if I manage to find a solution ASAP I will reply here :)